# Signing an Android .apk from a 32 hex pair signing key

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signing, google-play-console

I have an android app that I have taken over development for and I am trying to push an update to the Google Play store.  The original developer has given me the signing key, but I am not sure how to create a certificate or keystore from this signing key.

key format I was given: 
`1B:96:51:EE...43`   (32 hex pair values separated by a colon)

I am familiar with creating a keystore from a self-signed certificate and using that keystore to sign the .apk.  But, I am not sure how to achieve this from the given signing key.

I have read over the documentation provided by Google [Google App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)
I do not see in this documentation how to utilize the signing key in the format it was given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this format, it is very unlikely that what he gave you is actually the signing key. This looks more like the certificate fingerprint, from which you would not be able to sign an APK.

You should request the previous developer to give you the keystore they were signing the APK with. This should be a file with the extension `jks`, `keystore`, or possibly `p12`.

If the app was enrolled in Play Signing, you could alternatively contact the Play Developer Support and ask them to reset the upload key (they will give you the instructions).